# Convert dataframe index to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

How do I convert a pandas index of strings to datetime format?

My dataframe `df` is like this:

```
                     value          
2015-09-25 00:46    71.925000
2015-09-25 00:47    71.625000
2015-09-25 00:48    71.333333
2015-09-25 00:49    64.571429
2015-09-25 00:50    72.285714
```

but the index is of type string, but I need it a datetime format because I get the error:

```
'Index' object has no attribute 'hour'
```

when using

```py
df["A"] = df.index.hour
```

Comment: `df.index.to_datetime()` or `df.index = pandas.to_datetime(df.index)` (the former is now deprecated).

Comment: type(df.index[1]) still returns 'str'

Comment: The data above converts to `datetime` no issues - `type(df.index[1]) == pandas.tslib.Timestamp`. Do you have bad data in the rest of the dataframe?

Comment: You may also specify format, and an errors kwag. Documentation of [`pandas.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) will explain the rest.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

It should work as expected. Try to run the following example.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = """value          
"2015-09-25 00:46"    71.925000
"2015-09-25 00:47"    71.625000
"2015-09-25 00:48"    71.333333
"2015-09-25 00:49"    64.571429
"2015-09-25 00:50"    72.285714"""

df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)

# Converting the index as date
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

# Extracting hour & minute
df['A'] = df.index.hour
df['B'] = df.index.minute
df

#                          value  A   B
# 2015-09-25 00:46:00  71.925000  0  46
# 2015-09-25 00:47:00  71.625000  0  47
# 2015-09-25 00:48:00  71.333333  0  48
# 2015-09-25 00:49:00  64.571429  0  49
# 2015-09-25 00:50:00  72.285714  0  50
```

Answer (score 11):

You could *explicitly create* a `DatetimeIndex` when initializing the dataframe. Assuming your data is in string format

```
data = [
    ('2015-09-25 00:46', '71.925000'),
    ('2015-09-25 00:47', '71.625000'),
    ('2015-09-25 00:48', '71.333333'),
    ('2015-09-25 00:49', '64.571429'),
    ('2015-09-25 00:50', '72.285714'),
]

index, values = zip(*data)

frame = pd.DataFrame({
    'values': values
}, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(index))

print(frame.index.minute)
```

Comment: FYI for Python3, you need `index, values = zip(*data.items())`

Answer (score 6):

I just give other option for this question - you need to use '.dt' in your code:

```html
import pandas as pd

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

#for get year
df.index.dt.year

#for get month
df.index.dt.month

#for get day
df.index.dt.day

#for get hour
df.index.dt.hour

#for get minute
df.index.dt.minute
```

Answer (score 4):

Doing

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, errors='coerce')
```

the data type of the index has changed to

[image: dataframe information]