# Pandas Plot with date time on x axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

In Pandas versions prior to 23.4 I could do this:

```
df.plot(x=df.DateTime, y=['var1', 'var2'])
```

With df.DateTime as a datetime type.      In v23.4 I get this error:

```
ValueError: x must be a label or position
```

I've been able to work around it based on advice in this thread: [plot x-axis as date in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49418248/plot-x-axis-as-date-in-matplotlib):

```
df = df.set_index(df.DateTime)
df.plot(y=['var1', 'var2'])   # i.e. don't specify x
```

My question: is this the right way to approach this with current Pandas and Matplotlib versions?

Comment: Does `df.plot(x = "DateTime", y=['var1', 'var2'])` not work? If not, then you have the only working solution as of now. Pandas always changes a couple of things from version to version. Also you can of course use matplotlib `plt.plot(df.DateTime.values, df[['var1', 'var2']].values)`.

Comment: df.plot(x = "DateTime", y=['var1', 'var2'])  does indeed work.   Instead of x being provided as a Series, it needs to be the label of a column.  My work around is not necessary.    Thanks.