# How to minimize the number of datetime ticks on the x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two lists: one is dates and othe is data.

```
alldates =    Index(['2019-01-25', '2019-01-26', ...'2019-05-09'], dtype='object')
data = [0.9868203770867318, .... ,0.9257586144368741]
```

I want to plot them. My code and result is:

```
plt.plot(alldates,data,'-*',label='R$^2$ score')
plt.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=5)
plt.ylim([-1,1.2])
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Plot is:

[image]

Also it was giving some error message:

```
    C:\Users\MMatam\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\ticker.py:
    1437: UserWarning: 'set_params()' not defined for locator 
of type <class 'matplotlib.category.StrCategoryLocator'>
          str(type(self)))
```

Did you see the x-axis ticks? Looks like my `plt.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=5)` did not work. How to get only few ticks on this axis?

Comment: @Vishnudev please dont quote this a duplicate without reading the question properly. I have already gone through the solution you have quoted but it is not same.

Comment: Try to change `alldates` into `datetime` type, not string.

Comment: @QuangHoang, I am new to python. Don't mind, how to change it?

Comment: You are not providing enough information, since I'm not sure what `alldates = Index(['2019-01-25', '2019-01-26', ...'2019-05-09'], dtype='object')` means. Does it come from a `pd` dataframe?

Comment: @QuangHoang it is just a list.

Comment: What's `Index`?

Comment: @QuangHoang I get this output when I do `print(alldates)`

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html

Comment: Then `alldates` is not just a list. `print(alldates)` is not equivalent to what it is. You should edit your question and include your **definition** of `alldates`.

Comment: The second comment is correct. Add `alldates = pd.to_datetime(alldates)` before plotting. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627686/plotting-dates-on-the-x-axis-with-pythons-matplotlib) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49418248/plot-x-axis-as-date-in-matplotlib).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I tried the second comment. It did minimize the sticks but not the definite number I wanted. The another source code you cited `.datestr2num(date)` did work perfectly. The only problem is, it converter the dates into a number. The number of sticks is same as I wanted.

Comment: For datetimes the number of ticks is rather unimportant because usually you do not want ticks at some 2019-04-19 14:23:46, but rather at the beginning of each month, or every monday, or everyday at noon or similar.