# Trouble plotting datetime pandas series with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

[image]

I'm trying to plot "created_at" versus "rating".

"Created_at" is datetime format

[image]

Why is the x-axis being shown as float values instead of dates like I am intending with the line

`plt.plot(data['created_at'].values, data['rating'],"b.", alpha =0.5)`

shown in the bottom picture

Comment: A sample of the actual total would help

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627686/plotting-dates-on-the-x-axis-with-pythons-matplotlib

Comment: try using `data["created_at"].values`.

Comment: I editted the question to be more explicitt. adding values did not change the x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is to define a temporary dataframe with the datetimes as index (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49418248/plot-x-axis-as-date-in-matplotlib)):

```
rating_vs_creationdate = data.copy()
rating_vs_creationdate = rating_vs_creationdate.set_index('created_at')
rating_vs_creationdate = rating_vs_creationdate['rating']
plt.plot(rating_vs_creationdate)
```

Maybe you will run into problems with the date format. The [link provided by MrFuppes in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627686/plotting-dates-on-the-x-axis-with-pythons-matplotlib) gives an easy date formatting example.