# How to plot x axis with minutes in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot x axis with every 60 minutes during ,and y axis with a list.

I've tried code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

date_time = ['08:30', '09:30', '10:30', '11:30', '12:30', '13:30', '14:30']

date_time = pd.to_datetime(date_time)
temp = [2, 4, 6, 4, 6,9,8]

DF = pd.DataFrame()
DF['temp'] = temp
DF = DF.set_index(date_time)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.plot(DF)
```

But the out put is x axis is like this one:[plot x-axis as date in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49418248/plot-x-axis-as-date-in-matplotlib) ,the x axis is not minutes but date,

my expected values on the X-axis are like :

```
'08:30' '09:30' '10:30' '11:30''12:30' '13:30' '14:30'
```

or

```
'08:30' '08:40' '08:50' '08:60' .... '15:00'
```

So how can I convert the date into the minutes data that I need,and also how can I convert the line into curve？

Any friends can hlep?

Comment: All minutes in your example equal 30. Please include expected values on the X-axis. Also, the line shown _is_ a curve. Please explain why you are not happy with it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply,I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

Update the axis formatter:

```
matplotlib.dates as mdates 
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M"))
plt.plot(DF)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply,but it still not works,could you show me the whole code?Best regards!

Comment: Simply add these lines before the last line.