# how to correctly plot regression output with right datetime index on x-axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I have air pollution time series data that I need to make a forward period estimation. To do so, I used randomforest regressor from `scikit-learn` to make prediction, and I want to visualize the prediction output but I have trouble visualizing the regression output where x-axis must show the right time index. Can suggest me how should I get better visualization for my below regression approach? Is there any better way to make this happen? Any idea?

**my attempt**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jerry-shad/36912907ba8660e11cd27be0d3e30639/raw/424f0891dc46d96cd5f867f3d2697777ac984f68/pollution.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=['date'])
df.date = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.date)
# df.sort_values(by='date').reset_index(drop=True)
df.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'],axis=1,inplace=True)
resultsDict={}
predictionsDict={}

split_date ='2017-12-01'
df_training = df.loc[df.date <= split_date]
df_test = df.loc[df.date > split_date]

## exclude pollution_index columns from training and testing data
df_tr = df_training.drop(['pollution_index'],axis=1)
df_te = df_test.drop(['pollution_index'],axis=1)

## scaling features
scaler = StandardScaler() 
scaler.fit(df_tr)
X_train = scaler.transform(df_tr)  
y_train = df_training['pollution_index']
X_test = scaler.transform(df_te)
y_test = df_test['pollution_index']

X_train_df = pd.DataFrame(X_train,columns=df_tr.columns)
X_test_df = pd.DataFrame(X_test,columns=df_te.columns)

reg = RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=2, random_state=0)
reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
yhat = reg.predict(X_test)
resultsDict['Randomforest'] = evaluate(df_test['eyci'], yhat)
predictionsDict['Randomforest'] = yhat

## print out prediction from RandomForest
print(predictionsDict['Randomforest'])
plt.plot(df_test['pollution_index'].values , label='Original')
plt.plot(yhat,color='red',label='predicted')
plt.legend()
```

**output of current attempt**

here is the output of the [image]above attempt:

In this attempt, I tried to make regression using randomforest regressor and intend to make simple plot but plot didn't show time on x-axis? Why? Does anyone know how to make this right? Any thoughts? Thanks

**desired plot**

Ideally, after trained the model, I want to make a forward period estimation, and this is the possible plot that I want to make from my above attempt:

[image]

Can anyone suggest to me the possible way of making the right visualization on regression output? Any thoughts?

Comment: Putting dates on axes is a recurring issue in matplotlib and as a result there are a lot of answers to this particular question on SO.

Comment: For example, this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49418248/plot-x-axis-as-date-in-matplotlib

Comment: Please strip your code to the essential in order to provide a [*minimal* reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to provide the dates explicitly to `matplotlib.pyplot.plot()`.

```py
plt.plot(df_test['date'],df_test['pollution_index'].values , label='Original')
plt.plot(df_test['date'],yhat,color='red',label='predicted')
```

You can also use the `matplotlib`-based plotting function from `pandas`:

```py
df_test['yhat'] = yhat
df_test.plot(x='date',y=['pollution_index','yhat'])
```

It automatically plots title, x/y labels and a legend.