# Change <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> to <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, stock

I have

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:AAPL_MIN.csv", parse_dates=True, index_col='datetime')
print(type(df.index))
```

how can I change type from <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> to <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>

datetime reads as 2020-09-14 09:30:00-04:00

Edit:

Here is an updated code with outputs

```
import pandas as pd    
    
df = pd.read_csv("file",header=0)

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

print(type(df['datetime'][0]))
#class 'datetime.datetime'

print(type(df['datetime']))
#class 'pandas.core.series.Series'

df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True, drop=True)

print(type(df.index))
#class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'
                             open     high      low    close   volume
datetime                                                              
2020-10-06 09:30:00-04:00  13.2800  13.3500  13.2300  13.2501  1060985
2020-10-06 09:31:00-04:00  13.2600  13.2600  13.1900  13.2150   377251
2020-10-06 09:32:00-04:00  13.2110  13.2299  13.1922  13.2143   391055
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python pandas convert index to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40815238/python-pandas-convert-index-to-datetime)

Comment: df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True

it does not it yields the above error

Comment: This detail is important to include in the initial question, as part of a [mcve]. Have you tried setting `utc=True` as in the error?

Comment: adding ```utc = True``` does not solve the issue no matter what I do I cannot get the index as a datetime even when I convert the column to datetime and set the column as index

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce. When I copy and paste the sample you provided, then do `df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)` followed by `df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)`, I get the dataframe with `type(df.index) == pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex`

Comment: So the above is just a sample of my csv. If I change my data frame to
```df = df[:3]``` it works. There must be a data validity issue somewhere in my 22,000 row file. thank you for your help

Comment: One way to check this is to do your `pd.to_datetime()` but use `errors='coerce'`, then look for `NaT` entries in the result

Answer (score 1):

**First Option**

Simply replace

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
```

with

```
df['datetime'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['datetime'])
```

Keep all other code the same.

The problem arises when you format the column with pd.to_datetime() and then convert it to an index.

**Second Option**

If what you want is to modify the current index, and not generate it again, another option would be:

```
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
```

**Thrid Option**

You can also do this step by step

1. Reset the index

`df = df.reset_index()`

2. Convert the column to the desired format

`df['datetime'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['datetime'])`

3. Converting it into an index

`df.set_index('datetime', inplace = True, drop = True)`

I had a similar problem and this solved it.

I hope it will help you.